# How to add columns to an existing SQL Server 2008 database table in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I'm looking to add 2 columns to an existing table in my SQL Server 2008 database. I'm coming in on a poorly documented project, so I wondering, is it simply a case of adding to the class and entering add migration?

The class is within an `Entities` folder in a `Models` project and the class uses the following attribute..

```
 [PersistableEntitiesAttribute]
```

The properties are written as...

```
   public virtual string Username { get; set; }
```

Can I add two virtual properties to the class and use the PM to add migration?

Please note I am seeking to keep all data already in the Database and there is no migrations folder in this project.

Asp.net MVC 3 application.

Is there steps I follow to complete this task ?

Comment: Is the project using EF Migrations?

Comment: I don't see a migrations folder anywhere.

Comment: It might be using a design-first approach, I'd have a look for an EDMX file. If that is the case, you should follow @marc_s advice and tag the question with the appropriate rdbms as that will have an effect on how you go about this.

Comment: Could I just add the virtual methods and manually add to the database?

Comment: How is the actual persistence done?  With a hand-coded DAL?  Through DataContext objects?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the correct way but I simply added the two virtual properties to my class..

```
  public virtual string ResetToken { get; set; }
  public virtual DateTime? ExpirationDateTime { get; set; }
```

and then added the same properties manually to the table in the database through the design view.